# Getting "JsonToWebElementConverter" exception when i am trying to connect with remote server to access the cloud devices

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, mobile-devices, selenium-remotedriver

Getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter
    at com.deloitte.convergeprosperity.bankingsuite.testRunners.AppiumTest.main(AppiumTest.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 1 more
```

i am trying to connect with remote server to access the cloud devices.